# Finding distinct pairs of values across multiple columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, count, unique, transformation

I have a csv file which I read into a dataframe in Python. I do various transformations to get the data into a format where each row item has some number of columns with attributes represented by a code. Not all rows have the same number of attributes so some columns are None type - for a given dataset the number of columns is arbitrary so general solutions involving the whole dataframe are preferred.

I attempted to count pairs of codes which I can do (though may be not an elegant or efficient solution).
I have the issue of not getting unique pairs - e.g. see the first and last rows of the output below.

I had thought about fixing this by sorting each row before looking for pairs  (not sure how to do that) or somehow manipulating the output I have to merge rows containing the same pairs.

Lastly, I would like to have a second output which only includes rows for which both columns start with a different letter.

Any help is appreciated.

A example dataframe -

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'0':['F048','B123','F048','F420'],'1':['B65D', 'B65D',None, None],'2':['G07C', 'F048', 'B65D', None]})
```

[image]

**What I tried was the following - **

```
# Count combination pairs
c = Counter([y for x in df2.values for y in combinations(x, 2)])
df = pd.DataFrame({'Pair': list(c.keys()), 'Qty': list(c.values())})
# Remove None
df = df[~df['Pair'].astype('string').str.contains("None", na=False)]
# Sort by quantity
df = df.sort_values(by = 'Qty', ascending = False)
```

**Output-**

[image]

In practice, my dataframe is significantly larger so if there is a more efficient way of doing this then that is also much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing strings so I guess there isn't more room for improvement using `pandas`.

You can try to replace the `"None"` string with pd.nan and drop it before the computation:

```py
from collections import Counter
from itertools import combinations

c = Counter()
x = df.replace("None", np.nan).stack().dropna()
x.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: c.update(combinations(x, 2)))

out = pd.DataFrame(c.items(), columns=["Pair", "Qty"])
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
           Pair  Qty
0  (F048, B65D)    2
1  (F048, G07C)    1
2  (B65D, G07C)    1
3  (B123, B65D)    1
4  (B123, F048)    1
5  (B65D, F048)    1
```

---

To get only unique pairs, you can use `frozenset`:

```py
c = Counter()
x = df.replace("None", np.nan).stack().dropna()
x.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: c.update(map(frozenset, combinations(x, 2))))

out = pd.DataFrame(c.items(), columns=["Pair", "Qty"])
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
           Pair  Qty
0  (B65D, F048)    3
1  (G07C, F048)    1
2  (B65D, G07C)    1
3  (B65D, B123)    1
4  (F048, B123)    1
```

Comment: Okay, thats a nice bit cleaner for that part, thanks.
Any ideas on how to only pick up unique/distinct pairs?

Comment: @Rob_does_physics Only where `Qty == 1`? `out = out[out.Qty.eq(1)]`

Comment: Not quite qty = 1.
E.g. the top and bottom rows are both the same pair (F048 and B65D) so I would like  way of merging these rows and adding the Qty together.

Comment: @Rob_does_physics IIUC you can use `frozenset`. I've updated my answer. But each column must have unique value. E.g. no `B65D, B65D, F048` in the columns.